# Is eMMC backup sufficient to restore NVRAM?

Tags: nandroid

Android flashing/backup guides often mention that NVRAM stores IMEI, WiFi MAC, etc., and that loosing it is real bad thing.

What bothers me is following:
NVRAM is, judging by name, RAM, so it sounds like it's not on eMMC. On the other hand, all the backup guides I found make me think that it's not true, at least not entirely.

---

So my questions are:

1. If I simply `dd` my phone's eMMC, will the resulting backup be sufficient to restore NVRAM?
2. Is it sufficient to just `dd` this backup back to eMMC?
3. (bonus) On average modern phone, is there any firmware/etc. that is **not** stored on eMMC and can be accidentally corrupted? (i.e. not counting e.g. eMMC's own firmware, which is hard to reach in general, even more so accidentally)

Comment: **nvram.bin** is supposed to be a file located in the **/efs** partition and, therefore, in the eMMC. It could never store data if it was a kind of RAM, since those memories are volatile by definition.

Comment: Well, it's NonVolatileRAM, that's why I'm asking. Although you probably are right, it has to be battery-backed or something so not very reliable.